# Concating a list of objects in Python for Pydub module

Tags: python, object, pydub

I'm attempting to join a list of wav files together into one audio file. So far this is what I have.
I can't wrap my head around how to sum the objects together though since they are each an object.

```
import glob, os
from pydub import AudioSegment

wavfiles = []
for file in glob.glob('*.WAV'):
    wavfiles.append(file)

outfile = "sounds.wav"

pydubobjects = []

for file in wavfiles:
    pydubobjects.append(AudioSegment.from_wav(file))


combined_sounds = sum(pydubobjects) #this is what doesn't work of course

# it should be like so
# combined_sounds = sound1 + sound2 + sound 3
# with each soundX being a pydub object

combined_sounds.export(outfile, format='wav')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sum` function is failing because its [starting value defaults to 0](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum), and you can't add an `AudioSegment` and an integer.

You just need to add a starting value like so:

```
combined_sounds = sum(pydubobjects, AudioSegment.empty())
```

In addition, you don't really need the separate loops if you just want to combine the files (and have no need for the intermediate lists of filenames or `AudioSegment` objects):

```
import glob
from pydub import AudioSegment

combined_sound = AudioSegment.empty()
for filename in glob.glob('*.wav'):
    combined_sound += AudioSegment.from_wav(filename)

outfile = "sounds.wav"
combined_sound.export(outfile, format='wav')
```