# How to sum every row of a permutation in python

Tags: python, audio, sum, permutation, pydub

My goal is to differently sum ten audio files obtained from the permutations in order to have a different audio file for each permutation (10! = 3 628 800 final audio in total) and export them as wav files.

Example (sound1 + sound3 + sound2+ sound4 + sound 8 + sound6 + sound5 + sound7 + sound10 + sound9 = first audio etc.)

How can I do this?. I tried but I'm having some trouble with the sum.

Here's what I've done so far

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import itertools

sound1 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/Users/Desktop/Countingpuppet/Music/1_R.wav")
sound2 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/Users/Desktop/Countingpuppet/Music/2_R.wav")
sound3 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/Users/Desktop/Countingpuppet/Music/3_R.wav")
sound4 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/Users/Desktop/Countingpuppet/Music/4_R.wav")
sound5 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/Users/Desktop/Countingpuppet/Music/5_R.wav")
sound6 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/Users/Desktop/Countingpuppet/Music/6_R.wav")
sound7 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/Users/Desktop/Countingpuppet/Music/7_R.wav")
sound8 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/Users/Desktop/Countingpuppet/Music/8_R.wav")
sound9 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/Users/Desktop/Countingpuppet/Music/9_R.wav")
sound10 = AudioSegment.from_wav("/Users/Desktop/Countingpuppet/Music/10_R.wav")

lis = (sound1,sound2,sound3,sound4,sound5,sound6,sound7,sound8,sound9,sound10)

list(itertools.permutations(lis))

dc = []
for i in range(1, len(lis) + 1):
    #sum(list(itertools.permutations(lis, i)))
    sum(lis(i))
    #dc += lis(i)

#combined_sounds = sound1 + sound2
#combined_sounds.export("/output/path.wav", format="wav")
```

Comment: Is the sum operator commutative?

Comment: with audio a+b+c  ==  b+a+c so result will be the same

Comment: uhm..Maybe I misspoke. What I want to obtain are all the possible sound sequences in audio format using 10 sounds (Example: 1,3,4,5,6,2,7,9,8,10; 10,1,4,2,3,5,7,6,8,9 etc. etc.). My idea to do this was to add up the individual audio for every sequence but I don't really know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Let `myPerm` be a permutation of the integers `{0,...,9}` you probably want this:

```
sum([lis(i) for i in myPerm])
```

but, if sum is commuative (i.e. `a+b == b+a`), you probably don't really want what you claim you want to achieve.

EDIT:

After I read your edit I think that you want to do the analogous of this

```
t = ("ba","a","c")
["".join(i) for i in itertools.permutations(t)]
```

for audio files.

By giving a look to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30204581/512225 
I deduce that you have to replace `"".join(i)` with `sum(i, AudioSegment.empty())`. I hope this solves your problem. (I didn't try it nyself on my machine)

Comment: Hi thanks. I don't think it's what I need, I have just added a comment above to better explain what I want